# Not Serializable exception Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

i´ve posted this question short time ago

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042130/save-array-of-drawable-to-file-android)

The answer was good but its really hard to do and i have to change most of my app logic.

so i searched for another solution, i found this: [Best way to Serialize / Deserialize an image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219023/best-way-to-serialize-deserialize-an-image-in-android)

So using that class i can serialize my arraylist of images without so much pain.

I´ve made needed changes to implement it, so my item class is at follows.

```
public class SeccionItem implements Serializable{
    String name;
    String text;
    ArrayList<SerializableImage> img;

    SeccionItem()
    {
        img = new ArrayList<SerializableImage>();
    }
}
```

But im still getting NotSerializableException for SeccionItem and i really dont know why.

I dont want to save each image on separate files from the input stream because i have many images related to a object and i dont want to have so much files for one part of my app.

code of serializableImage

```
public class SerializableImage implements Serializable {

private transient static final int NO_IMAGE = -1;

private transient Bitmap image;

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.image = image;
}

SerializableImage(Bitmap b)
{
    image = b;
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    if (image != null) {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        final byte[] imageByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        out.writeInt(imageByteArray.length);
        out.write(imageByteArray);
    } else {
        out.writeInt(NO_IMAGE);
    }
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
final int length = in.readInt();

if (length != NO_IMAGE) {
final byte[] imageByteArray = new byte[length];
image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, length);
}
}
```

Logcat just says WriteAbortedException caused by NotSerializableException on my call to oos.writeObject(data);

Complete stack trace

```
06-11 13:23:51.429: W/System.err(22409): java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.app.SeccionItem
06-11 13:23:51.449: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:933)
06-11 13:23:51.449: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
06-11 13:23:51.459: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
06-11 13:23:51.459: W/System.err(22409):    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:665)
06-11 13:23:51.459: W/System.err(22409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 13:23:51.469: W/System.err(22409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-11 13:23:51.469: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1520)
06-11 13:23:51.469: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1443)
06-11 13:23:51.469: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2112)
06-11 13:23:51.469: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:916)
06-11 13:23:51.469: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
06-11 13:23:51.479: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
06-11 13:23:51.479: W/System.err(22409):    at com.example.app.CachedContent.getData(CachedContent.java:35)
06-11 13:23:51.479: W/System.err(22409):    at com.example.app.SeccionParser.load(SeccionParser.java:46)
06-11 13:23:51.479: W/System.err(22409):    at com.example.app.Downloader.run(Downloader.java:28)
06-11 13:23:51.479: W/System.err(22409): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.app.SeccionItem
06-11 13:23:51.479: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
06-11 13:23:51.479: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
06-11 13:23:51.479: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
06-11 13:23:51.489: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
06-11 13:23:51.489: W/System.err(22409):    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:651)
06-11 13:23:51.489: W/System.err(22409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 13:23:51.499: W/System.err(22409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-11 13:23:51.499: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
06-11 13:23:51.499: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
06-11 13:23:51.499: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
06-11 13:23:51.499: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
06-11 13:23:51.499: W/System.err(22409):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
06-11 13:23:51.499: W/System.err(22409):    at com.example.app.CachedContent.saveData(CachedContent.java:22)
06-11 13:23:51.499: W/System.err(22409):    at com.example.app.SeccionParser.load(SeccionParser.java:78)
06-11 13:23:51.499: W/System.err(22409):    ... 1 more
```

CachedContent class:

```
public class CachedContent {

public static void saveData(String filename,Context context,ArrayList<?> data)
{
    try{
        File path = new File(context.getFilesDir(),filename);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
        oos.writeObject(data);
        oos.close();
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ArrayList<?> getData(String filename,Context context)
{
    try{
        File path = new File(context.getFilesDir(),filename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        ArrayList<?> data = (ArrayList<?>)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return data;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static void saveDate(Date date, String filename,Context context)
{
    try{
        File path = new File(context.getFilesDir(),filename+"_date");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
        oos.writeObject(date);
        oos.close();
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Date getDate(String filename,Context context)
{
    try{
        File path = new File(context.getFilesDir(),filename+"_date");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        Date d =(Date)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return d;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static boolean hasInternet(Context a){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)a.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(netInfo!=null && netInfo.isConnected()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Are `SeccionItem` or `SerializableImage` nested classes? They have to be defined in their own files, it won't work as nested classes.

Comment: they are on their own file each one

Comment: Please add the logcat and the code for `SerializableImage`.

Comment: The stack trace doesn't seem to be complete. Please add the rest.

Comment: I just tested your code and it works. Please add the code for `com.example.app.CachedContent.saveData()`.

Comment: Everything is working fine here. Maybe there is a problem with the image you want to save. Maybe it's too big. You could try it with a small bitmap, for example your app icon.